# Add string to the beginning of a gulp stream

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have setup a gulpfile.js that will compile my directory of js files to one (minified) source. But I need a small snippet of code to proced it (initializing the object literal that they are modifying), but I cannot seem to figure out how to achieve this. (See gulpfile below)

```
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('ethereal.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
        .pipe(rename('ethereal.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/*.js', ["lint", "build"]);
})
```

Each file in src modifies an object literal that I need to add to the very beginning of the output script

For example, src/Game.js is as follows:

```
Ethereal.Game = function() {
    // init game code
}
```

Notice how it assumes that Ethereal is a real object that it is modifying, which it is.

## TL;DR

1. How would I add a snippet of code to the beginning of a gulp stream file
2. If that's not possible how would I be able to achieve such an effect with another tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a file with the snippet to be included first and do this:

**src/first.js**

```
var Ethereal = function() {
    // define Ethereal class constructor and stuff
}
```

**src/Game.js**

```
Ethereal.Game = function() {
    // init game code
}
```

Then in the gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/first.js', 'src/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('ethereal.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
        .pipe(rename('ethereal.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

This will output **build/ethereal.js** as

```
var Ethereal = function() {
    // define Ethereal class constructor and stuff
} 
Ethereal.Game = function() {
    // init game code
}
```

or just use http://browserify.org/ and require the `Ethereal` module in every module that implements it.

Comment: sorry for the nooby question, but I am very new to build systems